# Need to return last purchase date for items that have not been purchased for more than 180 days

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime

Building report for slow movers in a a database.  I want to know items that have not been purchases in 180 days and show the most recent purchase date.  The dates ares store in datetime format mm/dd/yyyy HH:MM:SS.000
this is my latest attempt I am trying to self learn sql to help at work so any help and explanation is appreciated.  The data base is MS SQL.

```
SELECT
    Inventory.LocalSKU, 
    InventorySuppliers.SupplierSKU, 
    MAX([Order Details].DetailDate)

FROM            
    Inventory INNER JOIN
    InventorySuppliers ON Inventory.LocalSKU = InventorySuppliers.LocalSKU 
    INNER JOIN
    [Order Details] ON InventorySuppliers.LocalSKU = [Order Details].SKU 
    CROSS JOIN
    POHistory

WHERE     
    GETDATE() >= CONVERT(date,DATEADD(DAY,+30,[Order Details].DetailDate))
ORDER  BY
    [Order Details].DetailDate DESC
```

Comment: Could you please provide db structure?

Comment: I am picking this up this db from a purchases access version and trying to migrate away Most of what I have to go on is just the table names. http://www.stoneedge.com/docs/OrderManagerDevelopersGuideV59.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try:

```
SELECT
    Inventory.LocalSKU, 
    InventorySuppliers.SupplierSKU, 
    MAX([Order Details].DetailDate)

FROM            
    Inventory INNER JOIN
    InventorySuppliers ON Inventory.LocalSKU = InventorySuppliers.LocalSKU 
    INNER JOIN
    [Order Details] ON InventorySuppliers.LocalSKU = [Order Details].SKU 
    CROSS JOIN
    POHistory

WHERE     
    GETDATE() >= CONVERT(date,DATEADD(DAY,180,[Order Details].DetailDate))
    GROUP BY
            Inventory.LocalSKU, 
            InventorySuppliers.SupplierSKU, 
ORDER  BY
    MAX([Order Details].DetailDate) DESC
```

Comment: Your WHERE clause will filter out orders older than xx days.  What you want to do instead is to identify products whose last order was more than xx days ago.

Comment: @PhilSandler The number was incorrect but otherwise it's the same as yours.

Comment: And won't it be better to filter out new records before grouping (for performance)?

Comment: Thanks to both Phil and Szymon. Great advice on grouping after filtering out.  I am learning as I go and definitely appreciate your help.  Thanks again.

Comment: It is *not* the same as mine, and does *not* do what the question is asking for.  If an inventory item was ordered yesterday, it will still come back in this query, since it is being filtered out.

Comment: From the question: *I want to know items that have not been purchases in 180 days and show the most recent purchase date.*

Comment: This worked great but I also need to return items that have never been ordered.

Comment: @Phil Sanders Both queries returned the same values

Comment: As far as returning NULL values I changed the join to   
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    [Order Details] ON InventorySuppliers.LocalSKU = [Order Details].SKU

Comment: @PhilSandler I may be wrong but how an item bought yesterday would meet the condition `GETDATE() >= CONVERT(date,DATEADD(DAY,180,[Order Details].DetailDate))`?

Comment: @Ike_at_USU It may be easiest to do a separate query for items not bought at all and do a `UNION`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (not syntax checked):

```
SELECT
    Inventory.LocalSKU, 
    InventorySuppliers.SupplierSKU, 
    MAX([Order Details].DetailDate)

FROM            
    Inventory 
    INNER JOIN InventorySuppliers ON Inventory.LocalSKU = InventorySuppliers.LocalSKU 
    INNER JOIN [Order Details] ON InventorySuppliers.LocalSKU = [Order Details].SKU 
    CROSS JOIN POHistory --what is this here for?
GROUP BY
    Inventory.LocalSKU, 
    InventorySuppliers.SupplierSKU
HAVING     
    --your question said 180 days, but your code had 30 days?
    GETDATE() >= CONVERT(date,DATEADD(DAY,180,MAX([Order Details].DetailDate)))
ORDER  BY
    [Order Details].DetailDate DESC
```

Comment: Sorry I had left thirty days in when I was testing to see if I was correctly affecting the returned values.  POHistory is for for later when I can check to see last time a PO was created for the product if I can get this to work.

Comment: I tried this code it worked as far as allowing me to use the max function but now the HAVING section no longer works it returns the same error as MAX did before

Answer (score 0):

This is the complete code I ended up using to Identify slow and zero movers thanks for everyone help.

```
    SELECT suppliers.suppliername, 
       inventory.localsku,
       inventorysuppliers.suppliersku,
       inventory.itemname, 
       inventory.Text2 as "Outlet",
       inventory.Text3 as "Season",
       inventory.Text5 as "Discount",
       inventory.qoh, 
       Max(CONVERT(DATE, [Order Details].detaildate)) AS [Last Ordered], 
       Max(CONVERT(DATE, pohistory.date))             AS [Last PO], 
       inventory.discontinued 
FROM   inventory 
       INNER JOIN inventorysuppliers 
               ON inventory.localsku = inventorysuppliers.localsku 
       INNER JOIN suppliers 
               ON inventorysuppliers.supplierid = suppliers.supplierid 
       INNER JOIN pohistory 
                    ON inventorysuppliers.suppliersku = pohistory.supplierssku 
       INNER JOIN [Order Details] 
                    ON inventorysuppliers.localsku = [Order Details].sku 
WHERE  ( Getdate() >= CONVERT(DATE, Dateadd(month, 6, [Order Details].detaildate)) ) 
       AND ( inventory.discontinued = 0 ) 
       AND ( Getdate() <= CONVERT(DATE, Dateadd(month, 5, pohistory.date)) )
       AND inventory.discontinued = 0 
OR
       ( [Order Details].detaildate IS NULL ) 
       AND ( inventory.discontinued = 0 ) 
       AND ( Getdate() <= CONVERT(DATE, Dateadd(month, 5, pohistory.date)) )
       AND inventory.discontinued = 0 

GROUP  BY inventory.localsku, 
          inventorysuppliers.suppliersku, 
          inventory.itemname, 
          suppliers.suppliername, 
          inventory.qoh, 
          inventory.discontinued, 
          inventory.Text2,
          inventory.Text3,
          inventory.Text5
HAVING    ( inventory.QOH > 0)

UNION

SELECT suppliers.suppliername, 
       inventory.localsku,
       inventorysuppliers.suppliersku,
       inventory.itemname, 
       inventory.Text2 as "Outlet",
       inventory.Text3 as "Season",
       inventory.Text5 as "Discount",
       inventory.qoh, 
       Max(CONVERT(DATE, [Order Details].detaildate)) AS [Last Ordered], 
       Max(CONVERT(DATE, pohistory.date))             AS [Last PO], 
       inventory.discontinued 
FROM   inventory 
       INNER JOIN inventorysuppliers 
               ON inventory.localsku = inventorysuppliers.localsku 
       INNER JOIN suppliers 
               ON inventorysuppliers.supplierid = suppliers.supplierid 
       INNER JOIN pohistory 
                    ON inventorysuppliers.suppliersku = pohistory.supplierssku 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN [Order Details] 
                    ON inventorysuppliers.localsku = [Order Details].sku 
WHERE      ( [Order Details].detaildate IS NULL ) 
       AND ( inventory.discontinued = 0 ) 
       AND ( Getdate() <= CONVERT(DATE, Dateadd(month, 5, pohistory.date)) )
       AND inventory.discontinued = 0 

GROUP  BY inventory.localsku, 
          inventorysuppliers.suppliersku, 
          inventory.itemname, 
          suppliers.suppliername, 
          inventory.qoh, 
          inventory.discontinued, 
          inventory.Text2,
          inventory.Text3,
          inventory.Text5
HAVING    ( inventory.QOH > 0)
ORDER  BY suppliers.suppliername
```